# AJAX Thread management in jQuery?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

forgive me if this has been covered, but I promise to have searched beforehand.
I got a chain of `AJAX` get-requests updating columns every 30 seconds.
On the basis of these updates, a button to load new content is displayed,
again loading new content and resetting the related session variable.

Of course, collisions occur.

ATM, I block each column individually through variables which are freed up again after `AJAX` success, while setInterval'ing if a variable is blocked.

Now, is there any elegant way to do this? I've fiddled with deferred objects and `.ajaxStop` but to no avail. I read somewhere, that jQuery 1.5 / `$.done()` etc. should introduce some kind of thread management for Ajax calls? How can I leverage this?

```
//timed update
function refresh() {

    if (BLOCKED != 1) {
        BLOCKED = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update',
            success: function(data) {
                 BLOCKED = 0;
            }
         });
     }

//click function
function load() {
    if (BLOCKED != 1) {
        BLOCKED = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/load'
        });
    } else setTimeout("load()", 500);
}
```

Comment: There are certainly ways to control access to things during an ajax call without using setInterval to poll anything.  But, we'd need to see more specifics of your situation to know what to suggest.  The key is that you know when you started your ajax call and the completion function tells you when it's done.  You can keep track of that state so you can know at any time whether a given ajax call is still inflight.

Comment: Just so you know, as far as JS is concerned, there are no "threads".  Or rather, there's always exactly one, which makes the whole concept of threading moot.  The word carries a pretty specific meaning that is not really applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest this that gets rid of the timer polling.  This sets a flag when a load is pending and when the update finishes, it checks to see if the next load is pending rather than polling for that:

```
// global state
var inFlight = false;
var pendingLoad = false;

function checkPendingLoad() {
    if (pendingLoad) {
        pendingLoad = false;
        load();
    }
}

function refresh() {
    if (!inFlight) {
        inflight = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update',
            complete: function(data) {
                 inFlight = false;
                 checkPendingLoad();
            }
         });
     }
}


//click function
function load() {
    if (!inFlight) {
        inFlight = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/load',
            complete: function(data) {
                inFlight = false;
                checkPendingLoad();
            }
        });
    } else {
        pendingLoad = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the success handlers to complete handlers so they are always called even in error conditions.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I was too focused on the fancy deferrer stuff.

Comment: @reinhardt - the deferred stuff could probably be used too, but doesn't really handle the pending load as well.